# UWP: Can't load and show Interstitial video ad

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to monetize my app with Universal Windows. I followed the official tutorials but when I tried to load an interstitial ad, always I'm getting this errors:

> Interstitial ad is not ready. With this error code: ClientConfiguration.
>
> Failed to make http requestError. With this error code: NetworkConnectionFailure.

I don't know what I am missing.

This is my code:

```
public sealed partial class Myclass: Page {
    InterstitialAd MyVideoAd;

    public MyClass() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        
        var MyAppId = "d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab";
        var MyAdUnitId = "11389925";
        
        MyVideoAd = new InterstitialAd();
        MyVideoAd.ErrorOccurred += MyVideoAd_ErrorOccurred;
        MyVideoAd.RequestAd(AdType.Video, MyAppId, MyAdUnitId);
    }

    private void MyVideoAd_ErrorOccurred(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs e) {
        String errrorMessage = e.ErrorMessage;
        String errorCode = e.ErrorCode;
    }

    private void showInterstitial(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {  
        MyVideoAd.Show();
    }
}
```

When I execute the application, a few seconds after the `MyVideoAd_ErrorOccurred` method is launched with the values of `errorMessage` and `errorCode` as I've said. That happens on my Windows 10 mobile device and in the Desktop machine execution. The codes of `adUnit` and application id are the provided in the Microsoft page for tests.

I hope that you can help me.

Comment: I'm trying to run this example https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Advertising/cs from gitHub Microsoft account and I'm getting the same errror.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have these 3 Capabilities defined inside your manifest:

```
<Capabilities>
  ...
  <Capability Name="internetClient"/>
  <Capability Name="internetClientServer"/>
  <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer"/>
  ...
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but yes, I have ALL Capagilities checked. And does not work  :(

Answer (score 0):

For UWP app, please install [Microsoft Universal Ad Client SDK](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/401703a0-263e-4949-8f0f-738305d6ef4b) and use AdMediatorControl.

References:

- [Install the Universal Ad Client SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/install-the-microsoft-universal-ad-client-sdk)
- [Add and use the ad mediator control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/add-and-use-the-ad-mediator-control)

Check my sample: https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/AdClientUWPApp

Comment: I have followed your steps exactly and i could achieve banner ad but whatever I tried, my Interstital ad never get ready state. I am getting InterstitialAdState as Closed. I tried both Display and Video. what couldnt be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The video hasn't finished loading. you need to give it enough time for that. also you need to make sure it is loaded before calling it with.

```
if ((InterstitialAdState.Ready) == (MyVideoAd.State))
{
  MyVideoAd.Show();
}
```